Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow_lite_support
TensorFlow SavedModel: export failure ❌ 24.0s: No module named 'tensorflow_lite_support'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\86182\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
return run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Users\86182\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\86182\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\yolo.exe_main.py", line 7, in 
sys.exit(entrypoint())
File "C:\Users\86182\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\cfg_init.py", line 591, in entrypoint
getattr(model, mode)(**overrides)  # default args from model
File "C:\Users\86182\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\model.py", line 602, in export
return Exporter(overrides=args, _callbacks=self.callbacks)(model=self.model)
File "C:\Users\86182\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\utils_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\86182\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\exporter.py", line 313, in call
f[5], keras_model = self.export_saved_model()
File "C:\Users\86182\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\exporter.py", line 142, in outer_func
raise e
File "C:\Users\86182\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\exporter.py", line 137, in outer_func
f, model = inner_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\86182\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\exporter.py", line 900, in export_saved_model
f.unlink() if "quant_with_int16_act.tflite" in str(f) else self._add_tflite_metadata(file)
File "C:\Users\86182\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\exporter.py", line 1023, in _add_tflite_metadata
from tensorflow_lite_support.metadata import metadata_schema_py_generated as schema  # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_lite_support'
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO('C:/Users/86182/runs/detect/train10/weights/best.pt')
model.export(format="tflite")
How can I fix this No module named 'tensorflow_lite_support' pip install could not find

Are you using the latest versions of torch and ultralytics? pip install --upgrade torch ultralytics

I recently encountered this issue and resolved it by editing the file located at '...\ultralytics\engine\exporter.py'.
import flatbuffers

# if ARM64:
from tflite_support import metadata  # noqa
from tflite_support import metadata_schema_py_generated as schema  # noqa
# else:
#     # TFLite Support bug https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-support/issues/954#issuecomment-2108570845
#     from tensorflow_lite_support.metadata import metadata_schema_py_generated as schema  # noqa
#     from tensorflow_lite_support.metadata.python import metadata  # noqa

# Create model info
model_meta = schema.ModelMetadataT()
model_meta.name = self.metadata["description"]
model_meta.version = self.metadata["version"]
model_meta.author = self.metadata["author"]
model_meta.license = self.metadata["license"]

There is a discussion here that might help you: GitHub Issue Discussion.

Not Fix but you can try google colab from ultralytics/issues/2317
it may helps...
here: Colab YOLOv8 to tflite
also check Issue
